# How are references implemented in Oracle's JVM?

Tags: java, object, reference

While searching for an explanation on how a reference variable is implemented in Java I came across this question:
[What's inside a reference variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447878/whats-inside-a-reference-variable-in-java)
In there was a comment by Samuel_xL saying that specifying the vendor name would be a better question.
So my question is that how an instance variable in implemented in Oracle JVM? Is it a pointer to an address? I know that a reference holds bits that tell the JVM how to access the object.
But how is it structured??

Comment: Essentially it's a plain old pointer to the object.  The only swizzle is that generally objects are allocated on an 8, 16, or 32 byte boundary, so the pointer can be shifted down by 3, 4, or 5 bits, to allow more high-order bits (and hence a larger max heap) when implementing references in a JVM with 32 bit references.  When 64-bit references are used this swizzle is not really needed (but 64-bit references put more strain on storage).

Comment: @HotLicks So in 64-bit case the reference size will always be 64 bits regardless of the size of the actual object it is referring to?

Comment: So far as I'm aware.  There have been a number of "oddball" JVMs over the years, so probably there's some exception to the rule somewhere, but there's no real point in paying the runtime cost (which is small but not entirely trivial) to swizzle the pointers if you have 64-bit refs.

Comment: (As an example of the oddballs, there was (quite a few years ago) a "technology demo" JVM for the IBM AS/400 that had 128-bit references, including 48 bits of address and several other pieces of data.  The eventual "product" version of the JVM, however, used 64-bit references.)

Comment: (I'm vaguely recalling that some early JVMs (or perhaps some other heap manager such as for LISP) had "tag" bits in the high order of the reference that told one how much to shift the ref to get the proper alignment.  Small objects would be allocated at finer boundaries and low addresses, while large objects would be allocated at coarse boundaries, allowing them to be at higher addresses.  But the tag bits themselves took away address space, so this was an iffy tradeoff.)

Comment: @HotLicks Much appreciated. Gave me a lot of new material to research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to determine, object references are stored either as a type called `oop` (ordinary object pointer) or `narrowOop`, depending on whether the JVM is using compressed object pointers or not. An `oop` is a C++ class that wraps a pointer to a Java object, and a `narrowOop` is a 32-bit unsigned integer that has to be converted into a proper pointer in order to access the object; they have no internal structure. You can find the declarations here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/oops/oopsHierarchy.hpp

Comment: Thank you I will look into these. Can you please tell me the name of a good book on JVM? I couldn't find much on google.

Comment: Is the reference implementation the same in Oracle JVM and OpenJDK's HotSpot?

Comment: I don't know if there's a book on JVM internals, such a book wouldn't have a very large audience since the subject is highly specialized. The Oracle JVM is based on OpenJDK AFAIK.